# ¿Cómo puedo convertir un dato char a int y Float?

Tags: c

Estoy creando un programa recibe una cadena de texto alfanumérica, y de esa cadena deseo extraer nada más los números y después convertirlos a int o float, pero no hallo como convertir de char a int o float, he intentado con esto y me da error:

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include<stdlib.h>

void Main(){
char texto[] = "H5ol6";
char x = texto[1];
int numero = atoi(x);
printf("%d",numero+2);
}
```

Este código lo ejecutó, pero me sale el siguiente error:

> note:expected "const char *" but argument si of type "char"
>
> extern int atoi (const char *__nptr)

Quisiera que me ayudarán a solucionarlo por favor o habrá otra forma de hacerlo que no sea tan compleja.

Comment: Hola Kelvin, recuerda evitar usar acentos en nombres de variables, saludos!

Answer (score 2):

Puedes usar TypeCasting usando `(int)` en lugar de `atoi`, ejemplo:

```
char texto[] = "H5ol6";
char x = texto[1];
int numero = (int)(x);
printf("%d",numero+2);
```

salida:

```
55
```

---

Actualización:

Hay un pequeño malentendido, al obtener el segundo carácter ('5') y [convertirlo a entero](http://asciivalue.com/) se obtiene 53, ya que esta es su representación:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Si deseas obtener el valor '5' debes restar el valor ASCII del carácter '0', por ejemplo:

```
char texto[] = "H5ol6";
char x = texto[1] - '0';
printf("%d\n",x);
```

salida:

```
5
```

por lo tanto, para lo que deseas, tu código sería:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include<stdlib.h>

void  main() {
  char texto[] = "H5ol6";
  char x = texto[1] - '0'; //estar el valor ASCII del carácter '0'
  int numero = (int)(x); //Obtiene el valor entero 5 
  printf("%d\n",numero+2);
}
```

salida:

```
7
```

Comment: Pero al ejecutar el código me devuelve el número 55, y yo solo quiero es 5 + 2 = 7

Comment: Hay un malentendido, al obtener el valor char de '5' y convertirlo a entero se obtiene  un decimal que es 53  , por eso al sumar 2 se obtiene 55. Lo que tu quieres es el valor de 5 no su representación a entero. Agregue una actualización de la respuesta para que lo comprendas, saludos. @KelvinRomero

Answer (score 0):

La función `atoi` recibe una cadena (`char*`). Se queja porque le estás pasando un solo caracter.

Si tu idea es leer números enteros. Como en "H60la" que tienes el número 60, puedes usar `atoi` pasando la cadena desde cierto carácter. Así:

```
int largo = strlen(texto);
for (int i = 0; i < largo; i++){
    int numero = atoi(&texto[i]);
    // ...
}
```

El inconveniente es que también lee el número 0. Así que si quisieras evitarlo deberías identificar números completos en la cadena y luego extraerlos.

Podrías hacer algo así:

```
int largo = strlen(texto);
int digitos = 0;
int separadorDecimalesLeido = 0;
for (int i = 0; i < largo; i++){
    int esDigito = texto[i] >= '0' && texto[i] <= '9';
    int esSepararadorDecimal = texto[i] == '.';
    // Contar los dígitos 
    if (esDigito || esSepararadorDecimal) {
        digitos++;
    }
    // Si hay dígitos contados y el caracter actual no es un dígito,
    // se imprime el número y la cuenta vuelve a 0.
    else if (digitos > 0) {
        float numero = atof(&texto[i - digitos]);
        printf("%f", numero);
        digitos = 0;
    }
}

// Se imprimen dígitos que hayan quedado final sin imprimir
if (digitos > 0) {
    float numero = atof(&texto[largo - digitos]);
    printf("%f", numero);
    digitos = 0;
}
```